# Ipatables rule to NAT if ip does not match a bunch of ips.

Tags: iptables

I have two server 192.168.0.153 and 192.168.0.200, I wish to send all incoming traffic to server 192.168.0.153:80 to 192.168.0.200:80

This can be achieved using the NAT table, but, I do not want the NAT to take place if the traffic to the server 192.168.0.153:80 is from 192.168.0.140, 192.168.0.142 or 192.168.0.143, rest all incoming connections to server 192.168.0.153:80 should be nat'ed to 192.168.0.200:80

How can I achieve this with iptables ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let the connections from the three authorized IP to go to .153.
Then, DNAT the other ones.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.140,192.168.0.142,192.168.0.143 -d 192.168.0.153 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.153 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.200
```